# Python regex not matching strings with symbols

Tags: python-2.7

I have a regex check that matches certain words in a file. I have greped the file so I know for certain that these strings are in there, however the regex doesn't find them.

I have tried raw strings, with and without word boundaries, as well as escaping the symbols. The strings match when I do not use word boundaries, however it then also matches other things that shouldn't be there. I think it might be to do with the symbols are the start of the string.

```
line = "Superuser.apk, /sbin/su, /su/bin/su, /su/fake/test"

wordlist = [Superuser.apk','com.topjohnwu.magisk','\/system\/bin\/su','\/system\/xbin\/su','\/sbin\/su','\/system\/su','\/su\/bin\/su']

complist = []

for word in wordlist:
        complist.extend([re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % word)])
        #complist.extend([re.compile(word)])

for lv in complist:
        match = lv.findall(line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

I would expect a match on the first 3 items, but not item 4.
Currently, it would only match 'Superuser.apk'

EDIT: More testing reveals that if my wordlist contains `bin/su` without the leading forward slash then it is found. Therefore it is the symbols that are not being matched. 
How would I solve this to match symbols as I have other patterns such as `://` and `/*` that need to be matched.

Comment: The word breaks `\b` are interfering, because they only match positions with a word character on one side and a not-word character on the other side. Thus, if your `word` happens to *end* with a not-word character, the `\b` at the end will match only if a word character follows.

Comment: thanks, yes that seems to be the issue. Is there anyway round this?